# iOS AFJSONRequestOperation returns empty results

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, afnetworking

I am trying to retrieve data using from a JSON request using AFJSONRequestOperation.
On success I am able to successfully retrieve the data but unable to complete the request and forward the data further for processing.

Following is my code

```
-(void) retrieveBrandList:(void (^)(NSArray *brandList))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    //__block NSArray *brandList =[[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSString *BrandListURL= http://127.0.0.1:8888/know/rest/brand
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    NSLog(@"Brand List URL = %@", BrandListURL);

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =[AFJSONRequestOperation
                                        JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request
                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                        {
                                            NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
                                            brandList = [self successBandList:responseObject]; // parsing the JSON response in separate method (success block code)
                                            if (success)
                                                success(brandList);
                                        }

                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                        {
                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error];
                                            if (failure)
                                                failure(error);
                                        }];

    [operation start];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];

}
```

Following is the data manager to retrieve data.

```
- (NSArray *)getBrandList
{
    @try
    {

       [brand retrieveBrandList:^(NSArray *brandList)
        {
        brands = brandList;
        }
        failure:^(NSError *error) {
        }];

        NSLog(@"Retriving Brand list completed");
        return brands;
    }

    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@ , Error while getting the brand list", e);
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

How do i complete the operation and use or store the results for further processing in some other method?

Answer (score 0):

```
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            self.jsonDictionary = jsonObject;
        }
```

and you can check for other option too but this worked for me

Comment: I am trying to create a framework where I don't have any GUI. All i want to do is store the results in some variable and complete the program execution

Comment: Yes so what is you are not able to do with this

Comment: Parsing the Json works fine. I have problem in returning the data. Because of asynchronous method of AFJSONRequestOperation.
This operation returns empty results

Comment: Did you check response with Charlse?

Comment: Could you please provide me the link from Charlse?